# Disable Facebook notifications for top stories?

Tags: facebook, notifications

In the last few days, I've started getting Facebook notifications both in the web app and on iOS for some status updates or photo uploads from friends.

The notifications have a star icon [image] and the URL includes `notif_t=top_news_story`, suggesting I get notifications for "top stories".

I would prefer it the way it was before, where I only get notifications for comments on my stuff, when I'm tagged in a picture etc.

I haven't yet found the setting to disable this. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came here looking for help on this same issue and instead found the answer myself and thought I would share:

- Click on the "Notifications" button / icon at the top left of your profile (third button to the right of the FB logo).
- Hover over the offending notification and an "x" will appear at the top right of the said notification.
- Click on the "x" ("Turn Off") and you will be asked to confirm "Turn off top friend activity notifications"

The End

Comment: Good work! Thank you. Will have to wait a while to see if it had the desired effect, but I would be surprised if this doesn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit notification settings from within Facebook.

[Facebook Notification Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I did look in those settings but didn't find anything that seemed to apply to this.

Answer (score 1):

On your Facebook homepage, on the bottom left, under the friends tab, click on *Close friends*. It won't show any friends if you haven't added any. What I did was I clicked **x** for every friend in the suggestions on the right and on the top right where there is a notifications tab. I chose off in the drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify what you meant by the "friends tab", here are Facebook's instructions which you helped me find: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=112320895539157 It also doesn't list any friends for me, but I'll try turning off notifications on that page and see if that solves it. The ones I did receive notifications for are some of the ones it suggested.

Comment: Seems just turning off the notifications wasn't enough. Also removed the suggested friends, now. Let's see if that works.

Comment: Just got another notification despite doing both things described above :/ So either that's not enough, or there's a delay until it takes.

Comment: It worked for me. Hopefully it is just a delay and works for you soon enough.

Do you by any chance have Facebook Mobile Texts activated? I am also having issues with that and was wondering if others did as well.

Comment: Thanks again – will have to wait and see. Don't have Facebook Mobile Texts active, unless it's on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

- Go to your messenger app
- Click on your `Profile` in the top left corner
- `Notifications`
- `Toggle story notifications`

Comment: Please read [answer].